# Need help learning about Network helper class

Tags: android, networking

so I am currently learning about Android, and I am required to make a network helper class, that will handle all my downloads, asynctasks, and network operations as a whole. I don't have idea how to do that, and just looking at a completed example wont help.
Could you please tell me where I can read about such a network helper class?

Comment: I thought stackoverflow was a valuable source to find information and places to learn when someone wants to educate himself, from people who know their way around. Judging by the flagging of my question, seems I have been wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a NetworkUtils POJO class, where you can declare all your AsyncTasks as private classes of NetworkUtils, and declare all necessary methods as public static, so they can be accessed easily from anywhere in your app. Typically you want to include a method to check for a valid data connection, and add any relevant method to your app such as, for example, utility methods to convert files to be uploaded/downloaded from and to byte arrays.

I would still suggest (even if you say you are not interested in examples) that you browse a few open source Android projects on Github and Bitbucket, some of those will surely include such a class. Browse SO questions for specific tasks that your NetworkUtils class should perform and this should give you an idea of how to implement individual methods.